# My Swift class variable is empty

Tags: ios, swift

[It's empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saHln.png)

How can I keep the name in class?
I will assign a variable value to the function I want to use and then I will use that variable in the load screen, my code is below:

```
 import UIKit

    class userInfo{
        var name : String

        init(name : String) {
            self.name = name
        }

    }
    class userLoginViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var lblSurucuAdi: UILabel!

        var userInfoClass :userInfo?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

               userGet() 


            print(userInfoClass?.name)  // But it is empty here

        func userGet()
        {


          self.userInfoClass = userInfo(name: "emrekacan") // I make the username "emrekacan"
        }
      }
```

Comment: I can't figure out how could the `userInfoClass` be `nil`. is `userGet()` somehow declared inside the `viewDidLoad` method instead of as a method of `userLoginViewController` class?

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code into my Xcode.

[image]

You are only missing an `}`. Everything else is fine. I wonder if you ever saw the 2 error messages in red or not?!

Answer (score -3):

In your case argument label equals to parameter name `name`. You can use different argument label and parameter name. Argument label is using outside function and parameter name is using inside.

```
// some code here
init(name userName : String) {
    self.name = userName
}
// other code here
func userGet() {
    self.userInfoClass = userInfo(name: "emrekacan")
}
```

Comment: 1) the line `self.name = name = userName` isn't valid. 2) Using a different parameter label and parameter name doesn't change the behavior so it does nothing to fix the problem.